# can't import librosa lib on windows - "sndfile not found"

Tags: pip, librosa

In jupyter on windows:

```
import librosa

/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/soundfile.py in <module>()
    140     _libname = _find_library('sndfile')
    141     if _libname is None:
--> 142         raise OSError('sndfile library not found')
    143     _snd = _ffi.dlopen(_libname)
    144 except OSError:

OSError: sndfile library not found
```

googling revealed that this issue is only on windows, on linux ok.
Seems like sndfile is c-library. Tried to install with pip - but sndfile not on pypi.

Comment: http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/#Download

Comment: @phd, let me try this thx!

Answer (score 4):

same problem,here is how I fixed it:

```
apt install libsndfile1
```

Answer (score 0):

apparently python3.8 , 3.7 not compatible. But I just made it work on my local PC.

1. delete python
2. install python3.6.5
3. install librosa, import is fine, no "sndfile" error.

[image: k]